# How to add an empty entry to masonry?

Tags: categories, loop, tags, masonry

I am using masonry js library for display posts in my wp installation. The problem with it is that you cannot really add anything between posts entries because absolute positioning is used. So either I should use js to hack into masonry to add the block I want, or I can customize wp categories/tags loop (that's where I need it) to add an empty entry, that I can use as placeholder, and place stuff on it with css.

So How can I add an empty entry to category and tag loop? In my case I need the empty entry to be ahead, so it should be like this:
- first the empty entry
- then normal loop continues

How to do it?

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'sk_masonry_script' );

//* Add custom body class to the head
add_filter( 'body_class', 'sk_body_class' );
function sk_body_class( $classes ) {
        if (is_home()||is_archive())
                $classes[] = 'masonry-page';
                return $classes;
}




//* Display Post thumbnail, Post title, Post content/excerpt, Post info and Post meta in masonry brick
add_action('genesis_meta','sk_masonry_layout');
function sk_masonry_layout() {
        if (is_home()||is_archive()) {

                //add_filter( 'genesis_pre_get_option_site_layout', '__genesis_return_full_width_content' );


                remove_action( 'genesis_entry_header', 'genesis_do_post_title' );
                remove_action( 'genesis_entry_header', 'genesis_post_info', 12 );
                remove_action( 'genesis_entry_header', 'genesis_entry_header_markup_open', 5 );
                remove_action( 'genesis_entry_header', 'genesis_entry_header_markup_close', 15 );

                remove_action( 'genesis_entry_content', 'genesis_do_post_image', 8 );
                remove_action( 'genesis_entry_content', 'genesis_do_post_content' );

                remove_action( 'genesis_entry_footer', 'genesis_post_meta' );

                add_action( 'genesis_entry_content', 'sk_masonry_block_post_image', 8 ) ;
                add_action( 'genesis_entry_content', 'sk_masonry_title_content', 9 );

                add_action( 'genesis_entry_footer', 'sk_masonry_entry_footer' );

                remove_action( 'genesis_before_loop', 'genesis_do_breadcrumbs' );
                add_action( 'genesis_before_content', 'genesis_do_breadcrumbs' );

                remove_action( 'genesis_before_loop', 'genesis_do_taxonomy_title_description', 15 );
                add_action( 'genesis_before_content', 'genesis_do_taxonomy_title_description', 15 );

                remove_action( 'genesis_before_loop', 'genesis_do_author_title_description', 15 );
                add_action( 'genesis_before_content', 'genesis_do_author_title_description', 15 );

                remove_action( 'genesis_before_loop', 'genesis_do_author_box_archive', 15 );
                add_action( 'genesis_before_content', 'genesis_do_author_box_archive', 15 );

                remove_action( 'genesis_before_loop', 'genesis_do_cpt_archive_title_description' );
                add_action( 'genesis_before_content', 'genesis_do_cpt_archive_title_description' );

                remove_action( 'genesis_after_endwhile', 'genesis_posts_nav' );
                add_action( 'genesis_after_content', 'genesis_posts_nav' );

        }
}

//* Helper function to display Post title and Post content/excerpt wrapped in a custom div
function sk_masonry_title_content() {
        echo '<div class="title-content">';
                genesis_do_post_title();
                genesis_do_post_content();
        echo '</div>';
}

//* Helper function to display Post info and Post meta
function sk_masonry_entry_footer() {
                genesis_post_info();
                genesis_post_meta();
}

//* Set the second parameter to width of your masonry brick (.home .entry, .archive .entry)
add_image_size( 'masonry-brick-image', 255, 0, TRUE );

//* Helper function to display featured image
//* Source: http://surefirewebservices.com/development/genesis-framework/using-the-genesis-featured-image
function sk_masonry_block_post_image() {
                $img = genesis_get_image( array( 'format' => 'html', 'size' => 'masonry-brick-image', 'attr' => array( 'class' => 'post-image' ) ) );
                printf( '<a href="%s" title="%s">%s</a>', get_permalink(), the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ), $img );
}

//* Add more link when using excerpts
function sk_excerpt_more($more) {
    return '<a class="more-link" href="'. get_permalink() . '">&nbsp;&nbsp;[Continue Reading]</a>';
}
add_filter('excerpt_more', 'sk_excerpt_more');

//* Modify the length of post excerpts
add_filter( 'excerpt_length', 'sk_excerpt_length' );
function sk_excerpt_length( $length ) {
        return 33; // pull first 10 words
}
```

Comment: Please show us the current way (in code) how you add data to Masonryjs that gets then displayed.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/sHQtZt4h

Comment: Not a pastebin ... with an [edit] please.

Comment: does not fit in code quotes

Comment: First: You can strip it down. Second: Yes it fits. Third: What's "code quotes"?